# Vuex $state issue

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex

I have error like this:
I previously thought that this is problem with router, but after creating new project with only vuex problem is still there

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIPp5.png)

This is my main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App'
import store from './store'

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
})
```

store.js:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    users: [
      {id: 1, name: 'Adrian', email: 'adrian@email.pl'},
      {id: 2, name: 'Magda', email: 'magda@email.pl'}
    ]
  }
})
```

and my component using $store:

```
<template>
  <div class="usersNames">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="user in usersNames">{{user.name}}</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: 'usersNames',
    computed: {
      usersNames() {
        return this.$store.state.users;
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your example should work http://jsbin.com/hiduzinadu/edit?html,js,output

Comment: So this is probably problem with node or some packages.

Comment: It's hard to say, because code you posted is actually working code.

Comment: I don't think the problem is node nor other packages. I believe there are some mistakes in other components, based on the error message.

Comment: There is only one other component doing nothing basicly.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples look like it should work, but I would like to offer a different strategy that I think would be an improvement and should also solve your problem.

Create a getter in your store for the data you're trying to access in your component.

So change your store to this:

```
 import Vue from 'vue'
 import Vuex from 'vuex'

  Vue.use(Vuex)

  export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
      users: [
       {id: 1, name: 'Adrian', email: 'adrian@email.pl'},
       {id: 2, name: 'Magda', email: 'magda@email.pl'}
      ]
    },
    getters:{
      users: state => return state.users
    }
  });
```

Then, in your component, use that getter to get your users.

```
<script>
 export default {
    name: 'usersNames',
    computed: {
     usersNames() {
       return this.$store.getters.users
    }
   }
 }
</script>
```

Comment: I used getters but now my error is: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getters' of undefined
    at VueComponent.usersNames (eval at <anonymous> (app.js:672), <anonymous>:10:28)`

Comment: It sounds like to me your vuex store is not be initialized correctly. This is why getters AND direct calls to state aren't working. Make sure you have `Vue.use(vuex)` in the correct place, or your store is not being correctly initialized in the root Vue instance.....I know it's in the code you posted, but that might be the root issue. What happens with you log out the `this.$store` in a component? Do you see an instance of the store?

Comment: this.$store returns: 'undefined' ;/

Comment: Exactly... Your store is not being initialized with Vue root instance correctly, so that's why getters (or any else related to your store) will not work properly. If you fee like it is being inialized, try logging out `this.$store` in your root Vue instance...if it's still undefined there, you know it's an initialization problem.

Comment: Ah, yes. store is a "named import" not a default, so the brackets are necessary. Glad you found the issue

Answer (score 0):

you could change main.js:import {store} from './store';

Comment: or modify store.js ：export default new Vuex.Store({})

Answer (score -1):

Seems your vuex not inject into vue properly.

Maybe not related to your question, but just for best practice, better use mapState helper;
In your component:

```
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'usersNames',
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      usersNames: 'users'
    }),
    yourLocalComputed () {}
  }
}
```